# Identify a Date range in a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list of type string that contain the following strings:

> I built the vehicle in 1985
>
> Ronald owned the vehicle from (December 5, 1901 – December 15, 1966) in Paris
>
> It broke down in December 5, 2001
>
> I owned these vehicles as well (Mazda RX8 and a Toyota Prius)

To extract the 3rd string which states the date in which the vehicle broke down, I use the following code after running the list of sentences in a foreach loop, where 'sentence' is the loop variable

```
var dateString = Regex.Match(sentence, @"broke ([^\)]+)").Groups[1].ToString();
```

But if I'm to identify the 2nd string which states a range of dates inside the bracket, how can I use regex to extract only the bracketed range of dates? (non-inclusive of the bracket) such that the output is only:

> December 5, 1901 – December 15, 1966

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, 
    @"(?<=\()         # Make sure the previous character is a (
    \w+\s+\d+,\s+\d+  # Match a date
    \s*\p{Pd}\s*      # Match a dash, surrounded by optional whitespace
    \w+\s+\d+,\s+\d+  # Match a date
    (?=\))            # Make sure the following character is a )", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace).Value;
```

will extract a date range that follows the specified format exactly.

Test it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/mW7sI3/1).

Comment: Thanks sir but I edited the question a bit to better clarify. What if I only wanted the brackets with the dates specified within them?

Comment: @Earthling: You mean that the regex should avoid a match of `Mazda etc.`? Do you know the exact format of your dates?

Comment: Yes sir it always appears as: (Month Day, Year - Month Day, Year)

Comment: Nice sir! THANK YOU for the explanation as well :)

Comment: Sir one last request to make it more accurate, what changes should be made in order to extract the same date format range from a string like this: "text text (more text; December 5, 1901 – December 15, 1966)  text text" Which means to skip the 'more text' and the semi colon as well and still extract the range please? :)

Comment: @Earthling: You can replace `(?<=\()` with `(?<=\(.*?)`. `.*?` matches any string, as short as possible.

Comment: I tried (?<=\(.*?) on regex101 and it yields no result for the query I stated in the comments sir

Comment: @Earthling: Regex101 doesn't support lookbehind assertions as fully as the .NET regex engine does. If you want a fully functional regex tester, I strongly suggest you take a look at [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com); it's not free but worth every penny.